# How to color points based on a variable, and display the legend based on another variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Take the following data as a sample.

```
df.sample <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                       authors = c("a","a","b","b","c"),
                       year = c(2010,2020,2015,2020,2016),
                       authorsYear = c("a 2010", "a 2020", "b 2015", "b 2020", "c 2016"),
                       value = c(20,21,15,16,10))
)

id authors  year   authorsYear   value
 1       a  2010      "a 2010"    20 
 2       a  2020      "a 2020"    21
 3       b  2015      "b 2015"    15
 4       b  2020      "b 2020"    16
 5       c  2016      "c 2016"    10
```

As you can see, I have 5 studies listed, some of which have the same authors, but they are different studies. I would like to color the points based on only "authors", meaning that the same authors will have the same color in my graph, but I want to have a legend based on "authorsYear".
I tried with defining

```
aes(y = value, x = time, group =AuthorsYear, color = Authors)
```

but it only displays the authors in the legend.
Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need here, because the legend will match color to what was used to fill the colors. In this case, you will have 3 different colors (a, b and c) but 5 different authorsYear values, so there is no 1:1 correspondence there. If you want to convey that information on the plot (different studies) but still color by author, you could maybe use "shape" to shape the points differently according to authorsYear

Comment: So you want 3 different colours, one of a, one for b and one for c. Then what should the legend display for authorsYear "a 2010" and what should it display for "a 2020"?

Comment: @Godrim The legend should display full list of studies... as in AuthorYear, in which some studies have the same color. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it. I added an aesthetic for shape. If you don't like the double legend, there are ways to selectively remove them.

```
ggplot(df.sample, aes(year,
                          value, 
                          color = authors,
                      shape = authorsYear)) +
  geom_point(size = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible manual way, but it does what you want. Hopefully someone smarter than me can figure out a solution that scales better.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df.sample <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        authors = c("a","a","b","b","c"),
                        year = c(2010,2020,2015,2020,2016),
                        authorsYear = c("a 2010", "a 2020", "b 2015", "b 2020", "c 2016"),
                        value = c(20,21,15,16,10))


legend_colours <- c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green")

ggplot(df.sample, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = authors)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col = authorsYear)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = legend_colours,
                     limits = df.sample$authorsYear)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>